# Neo4j select nodes that are specific "type" (having specific label)

Tags: neo4j

For some reason I want to select all nodes that are into a specific type for in other words I want to extend the query:

```
MATCH (p) RETURN p
```

That will return all nodes that are these specific types:

- DATA_ASSET
- SERVER_OR_SERVICE
- APPLICATION
- DATA_CONSUMER
- PROSESED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that each node has **ONLY ONE** label this can be done with the following neo4j query:

```
MATCH (p) WHERE labels(p)[0] IN ['DATA_ASSET',
'SERVER_OR_SERVICE',
'APPLICATION',
'DATA_CONSUMER',
'PROSESED'] RETURN p
```